# obtener valores de un diccionario en especifico "python"

Tags: python, json, diccionarios

Tengo este diccionario y me gustaría saber que código usar para que me muestre solo los "symbols" y "descriptions" de la misma forma como se ve:

```
{
"securities": {
    "security": [
        {
            "symbol": "$AMUS",
            "exchange": "SPI",
            "type": "index",
            "description": "Alerian US Midstream Energy Index"  
        },
        {
            "symbol": "$AMZ",
            "exchange": "SPI",
            "type": "index",
            "description": "Alerian MLP Index"
        }
```

Me gustaria que el resultado se viera así:

```
"securities": {
"security": [
    {
        "symbol": "$AMUS",
        "description": "Alerian US Midstream Energy Index"  
    },
    {
        "symbol": "$AMZ",
        "description": "Alerian MLP Index"
    }
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [obetener valores especificos de un diccionario en python](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/529263/obetener-valores-especificos-de-un-diccionario-en-python)

Comment: no, no la responde, gracias

Comment: Ya, ya vi por qué no te funcionó, si era la misma pregunta que se había planteado pero sin respuesta... por lo que recuerdo, del mismo usuario

Comment: exactamente, esta vez la plantee de mejor forma, me parece.  Necesito ayuda con ésto, porque es un diccionario muy grande

Comment: Te comento referente al sitio, si la pregunta anterior que habías hecho no estaba bien planteada, tenías la opción de **editar** para añadir más detalles, no era necesaria una nueva pregunta. Lee [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) o en todo caso, visita el [centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help).

Comment: A que te refieres con "muestre solo los symbols y descriptions"? ¿Quieres acceder a los valores de esos campos y devolver un diccionario o solo los valores?... Si editas la pregunta y muestra un ejemplo de como quieres el resultado final estoy seguro que alguien te dará una respuesta más rápido.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Gracias por las respuestas, lamento si no logro explicarme bien, soy malo en lo que a expresarse se refiere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dict = {
    "securities": {
        "security": [
            {
                "symbol": "$AMUS",
                "exchange": "SPI",
                "type": "index",
                "description": "Alerian US Midstream Energy Index"  
            },
            {
                "symbol": "$AMZ",
                "exchange": "SPI",
                "type": "index",
                "description": "Alerian MLP Index"
            }
        ]
    }
}

def extraerDatos(sec):
    return {
        "symbol": sec['symbol'],
        "description": sec['description']
    }

dict['securities']['security'] = list(map(extraerDatos, dict['securities']['security']))

print(dict)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias la respuesta,  me genera el resultado de ésta forma: {'securities': {'security': [{'symbol': '$AMUS', 'description': 'Alerian US Midstream Energy Index'}, {'symbol': '$AMZ', 'description': 'Alerian MLP Index'}